# Could not create 'project properly says cakephp console in win 8

Tags: php, cakephp, console

With the hope that my tryst with cakephp will not come to an end, here I am posting a problem, may not be a new one in the group, however here is what i faced:

Created environment variable on my win 8, pointing to cake/app/console,  path to php server and mysql server. When I tried to bake the project, cmd console did spit a line : **“Could not create 'prayatna' properly”** (prayatna is the project name). Then I tried again downgrading apache, php versions. Cake versions. But the same line on cmd…

Any friends here experienced the same? Did find solutions? Request to share here.